# Фильтровать те данные, которые выбрал пользователь

Tags: javascript, ajax

У меня есть форма, которая посылает данные, проблема в одном в переменной str, там с помощью & данные идут только по порядку, но пользователь может выбрать любой порядок, допустим изначально filterCateg, то данные не будут отображаться. Если or использовать, то невозможно будет 2 и более запросов сделать

```js
<script>
  function f(fromDate=null, beforeDate=null, filterTyp=0, filterCateg=0, filterAccount=0, filterOrgan=0) {
    var fromDate = $("#fromDate").val();
    var beforeDate = $("#beforeDate").val();
    var filterTyp = $("#filterTyp").val();
    var filterCateg = $("#filterCateg").val();
    var filterAccount = $("#filterAccount").val();
    var filterOrgan = $("#filterOrgan").val();
    var str = "fromDate="+fromDate+"&beforeDate="+beforeDate+"&filterTyp="+filterTyp+"&filterCateg="+filterCateg+"&filterAccount="+filterAccount+"&filterOrgan="+filterOrgan;
    $.ajax({
      url: "TransTable.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: str,
      success: function(data)
      {
        $("#TransTable").html(data);
      }
    });
  }
  </script>
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="f(fromDate, beforeDate, filterTyp, filterCateg, filterAccount, filterOrgan)" name="filter" id="filterButtom" value="Фильтровать">
```

Comment: либо у Вас нет проблемы, либо вы не всё изложили в вопросе.Какая именно и где проблема у Вас возникла? от того что beforeDate и fromDate в строке поменяются местами, на сервере абсолютно ничего не изменится. Они все попадут в ассоциативный массив и оттуда будут доставаться по соответствующим ключам (beforeDate,fromDate и т.п.) Значения привязаны к конкретным полям. Как они могут поменяться?

Comment: а каков смысл использовать параметры в функции если Вы их не используете? Вы же переопределяете все переменные и получаете их из формы непосредственно в функции и игнорируете параметры, чтобы вы туда не передали.

Comment: для того чтобы Вам могли помочь опишите, пожалуйста подробнее в чём заключается Ваша проблема, без предположений из-за чего она может быть. Напишите подробнее в вопросе что делает Ваша форма, что происходит по факту после отправки формы и что должно происходить. Наблюдалось ли вообще правильное поведение у формы и если да, то в каких случаях. Если  ошибка проявляется в каких то определенных условиях, то опишите их тоже.

Comment: `&` в запросе это не элемент булевой алгебры. OR  быть в запросе не может.

Comment: и да, мы все с нетерпением ждём исходный код TransTable.php. Проблема наверняка в нём

Comment: @МихаилРебров в принципе по этому вопросу я решил, тем что значение все select переопределил value а не id. Но сейчас возникла новая проблема, что таблица перестала сортировать данные и при отметке checkbox, должна загорать кнопка "удалить запись". Если нужно то я скидываю исходник TransTable https://www.dropbox.com/s/vsegvcs6m0annq7/TransTable.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то у Вас намешано. Как соотносятся параметр `fromDate`, локальная переменная `fromDate` и глобальная переменная `fromDate` в вызове `onclick="f(fromDate,...`?

```
function f() {
  var fromDate = $("#fromDate").val();
  ...
  $.ajax({
    url: "TransTable.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      fromDate: fromDate,
      beforeDate: beforeDate,
      filterTyp: filterTyp,
      filterCateg: filterCateg,
      filterAccount: filterAccount,
      filterOrgan: filterOrgan
    },
    ...

<input type="button" onclick="f()" ...
```

Comment: @Игорь так у меня не фильтрует

Comment: Сорри, забыл запятую поставить

Comment: @Руслан Что у Вас "не фильтрует"? Вы говорите о серверном php коде? Где он?

Comment: Нет, все равно не получается.так как нужно, у меня ничего не выходит

Comment: @Руслан Потому что Вы делаете это неправильно.

Comment: а как тогда правильно?

Comment: @Руслан Откуда я знаю? Вы же не показываете код, который "фильтрует".